# Extending Object prototype in ActionScript 3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, prototype, extending

Whenever I try to extend the Object prototype, I get an error:

> Error #1056: Cannot create property my_extension on mx.core.UIComponentDescriptor.

I searched around, and found these:

[Flash AS3: ReferenceError: Error #1056: Cannot create property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1734169/flash-as3-referenceerror-error-1056-cannot-create-property)

[ReferenceError: Error #1056 - instance name Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2240011/referenceerror-error-1056-instance-name-problem)

I'm not using a visual IDE for designing a stage, but MXML and AS3 files, so I'm not sure what to make of this error.

My code:

```
Object.prototype.keys = function(): Array {
  var keys: Array = [];

  for (var key: * in this) {
    keys.push(key);
  }

  return keys;
}

Object.prototype.values = function(): Array {
  var values: Array = [];

  for each (var value: * in this) {
    values.push(value);
  }

  return values;
}
```

Comment: put code in bracers : object["keys"](); , because if You write without on nondynamic object , You will get compile-time error.
Anyway , I would advice You for example: create class ObjectUtil and inside function getKeys , than use ObjectUtil.getKeys(myObject);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `prototype` to extend a class seems very ActionScript 1 or 2.

In AS3, you may be able to prototype if the class is dynamic.

There are downsides to prototype:

- Only dynamic classes can be extended, one can not add methods to Math for example.
- Calls to methods stored in the prototype take longer to execute.
- Since methods are added at run-time, editors can not show them with code hinting or use the correct syntax highlighting.

Since all classes extend object, it is not necessary to explicitly declare `Object` as a base; however, you could define an AbstractObject class to be extended:

```
package
{

    public dynamic class AbstractObject extends Object
    {

        public function AbstractObject()
        {
            super();
        }

        public function get keys():Array
        {
            var keys:Array = [];

            for (var key:* in this)
            {
                keys.push(key);
            }

            return keys;
        }

        public function get values():Array
        {
            var values:Array = [];

            for each (var value:* in this)
            {
                values.push(value);
            }

            return values;
        }

    }
}
```

Subtype `AbstractObject` for your classes.

Comment: Do you need extends Object? I thought every class was an object by default?

Comment: No, which I stated in my answer.

Comment: Extending Object won't work for my purposes.  I still don't really understand - are you implying Object is a static class?

Comment: Instead of prototyping members on to class definitions, use object oriented paradigms of development by extending a base class.  Otherwise, use some static `ObjectUtil` class as recommended for this functionality.

Comment: I +1 this great answer and plus the guy asking the question will probably not accept any answers.

Comment: Although I've seen plenty of people mention it, I have never seen any benchmarks that prove there is a impact on performance when adding methods to a native type's prototype. I know that Flash looks for Class-level methods first, and then prototype methods if none are found in the class, but in the case of native types, isn't every method on the prototype?

For reference, I found this short article about extending "core types" http://tobyho.com/2009/05/02/modifying-core-types-in/

Comment: I would like to mention that what brought me here is that I am rewriting a bunch of Array methods that have been introduced recently in JavaScript. I (unfortunately) am required to use ActionScript because I work in adtech, and I'm trying to use as much of the recent advancements in ecmascript as I can to improve my code. 

Aside from mutating the prototype or extending native types, you may also use `call()` on your method. For example, `ArrayUtils.reduceRight.call([1,2,3], myReducerFn)`.

Comment: @SteveMason Internally within the AVM2, traits object is optimized with details of a class, reducing memory and reducing direct machine instructions.  Prototype chains are legacy, providing an alternative inheritance mechanism, and incur overhead in strict mode requiring dynamic type checking.