# How to embed font on dynamic text

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, fonts

> Fonts should be embedded for any text that may be edited at runtime, other than text with the "Use Device Fonts" setting. Use the Text > Font Embedding command to embed fonts.

Research done:

- [ReferenceError: Error #1056 - instance name Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2240011/referenceerror-error-1056-instance-name-error)

The above link gives a good direction (in the answers) for the problem:

Snippet:

> ...You can also get this error if you try to dynamically assign a variable to an object that doesn't naturally accept one like a textField.

So I have to click on the movieclip containing the text and then click on text and embed it.

But it still gives the error when I have clicked all the required symbols pressed ok and rerunned the movie?

It's probably very simple but i couldn't find out how to make the embed "stick" because each time I retry to embed it the selections are gone...?

Answer (score 0):

What is the version of Flash IDE you using? In the Flash CS 6 when you embed font in the text field it appears in the library (F11) of your fla file. You can edit the character ranges here and all text fields in this fla file will use it so you haven't to embed font for every field.

Comment: cs6 is the flash i'm using

Comment: I tried to reproduce this case but have failed. I only can advice you to make some experiments with embedding fonts in new empty fla it'll remove the influence of environment.

Answer (score 0):

With your FLA file open in Animate, open the Font Embedding dialog box by doing one of the following:

Choose Text > Font Embedding.

From the Library panel options menu, choose Add Font.

Right-click in empty space in the Library panel tree view, and choose New Font.

In the Text Property inspector, click on the Embed button.

https://helpx.adobe.com/animate/using/embed-fonts-consistent-text-appearance.html